# Grunt watcher isn't working anymore

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I've used grunt with grunt watcher: siteaccess  some time. To compile my less into css.
I use phpstorm.

But somehow it won't work anymore! I don't know why but it won't really install grunt. it works when i use grunt cache but not grunt watche. 
Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What is the output of grunt watch?

Comment: I had a rather similar issue, although I use grunt in the terminal alone, and in my case the folder / file tree I was watching was simply too big.

Comment: @omeinusch The normal output: Running "watcher:OI" (watcher) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...


But nothing happens..

Comment: What are you watching for?? Can you post your gruntfile.js contents for us?